# How to cast the generic result of a generic Swift method?

Tags: swift, generics

Assuming I have overloaded a Swift method like this

```
func someValue<T> ( _ name: PropertyName ) -> T? {
    // ...
}

func someValue ( _ name: PropertyName ) -> URL? {
    // ...
}
```

I can call this method like this

```
let u = o.someValue("propA")
```

And `u` will be of type `URL?`. Or I can also call it like this

```
let i: Int? = o.someValue("propB")
let s: String? = o.someValue("propC")
```

And `i` will be `Int?` and `s` will be `String?`.

But how can I use the result of this method call without assigning it to a variable? E.g. I want to use it `for` loop or maybe simpler, in a `switch` statement:

```
switch o.someValue("propB") {
```

This call will assume the result is `URL?`:

```
switch o.someValue("propB") as? Int {
```

I am told that `URL?` cannot be casted to `Int`, which is correct. But `URL?` means that already the wrong method is being called in the first place.

**Update**
Here is a minimal test case as I must not post the original code here.

https://swiftfiddle.com/srkys22vofdqlpl2sglnfs4q5u

Comment: `let i: Int = o.someValue("propB")` does *not* compile in my test. But `let i: Int? = o.someValue("propB")` compiles, and so does `switch o.someValue("propB") as Int? { ... }`. If you change the return type of the generic method to `T` then both `let i: Int = o.someValue("propB")` and `switch o.someValue("propB") as Int { ... }` compile. So I cannot see a problem. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR As for `Int` vs `Int?`, you are of course correct, I missed the question mark (didn't actually copy code there as I had to obfuscate the real code quickly) but that should have been obvious by the sentence below stating that the type of `i` is `Int?`, which of course implies that the type qualifier cannot be just `Int`, right?

Comment: @Mecki: Well, it is difficult to answer if the posted code does not reveal the claimed behavior. And the statement *“Doesn't work, nor does as? Int or as Int? work”* is still not correct, because it *does* compile with `as Int?`.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch o.someValue("propB") as? Int {
```

will not work as the compiler interprets that as

```
(switch o.someValue("propB")) as? Int {
```

in which case the `URL?` returning method wins, which is most specific overload, and then the case will fails as `URL?` cannot be cased to `Int`.

And then pointed out, that the correct code needs to be

```
switch o.someValue("propB") as Int? {
```

Note how the question mark is the only thing that moved here. As now the cast can match the generic version, too. This is basically hinted by the first line of Jessy's answer.